# Change Application Folder Path of Windows CE Setup Project

Tags: c#, installation, windows-ce, cab

I've created an application for Windows CE and I'm trying to create a setup project. I'm doing a silent update operation and need to install the .CAB files to a specific folder (\Program Files\abc\xx)

By default, it installs to \Program Files\Product Name

How can I make it to install on \Program Files\abc\xx ?

This was possible for windows installers but I guess not possible for Windows CE installers.

Thank you

Comment: Are you building your .CAB with your own custom INF?  Or within Studio 2005?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to modify the [INF file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa448654.aspx) that CABWiz is using (specifically the InstallDir in the [CEStrings section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms913648.aspx)).

If you're using the Studio project that wraps this INF file, then you can't adjust it (one of the many shortcomings of the device CAB installer projects).